# Ethereum development environment for Windows 10

Tags: solidity, blockchain, atom

I am new to Ethereum and Solidity. Currently learning it from youtube videos and some blogs.

So far I have been doing stuff in the remix IDE on a browser.  Now I want to perform the same things on my computer, so what would be an ideal setup for developing ÐApps with Ethereum and Solidity on my PC.

Also I use GoLand for Go and Atom as code editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below link for the starting development of DApps on ethereum using the local environment on windows.
[Ethereum Development On Windows](https://medium.com/edgefund/ethereum-development-on-windows-part-1-da260f6a6c06)

Answer (score 0):

Old question but for anyone who still visits this question.

You can run ethereum, truffle, ganache-cli, brownie, Hardhat, go-ethereum, even Cardano - cabal, ghc, stack, haskell with this windows 10 setup

- wsl2
- ubuntu wsl2 windows app
- vscode

Follow the instructions for wsl2 setup...then add ubuntu app...restart system then open ubuntu and install

- wget or curl
- python3.8 or 3.9
- pip
- git
- nvm - (node version manager)
- yarn (choose classic or new version depending on your needs)
- go

When you want to use vscode, from the Ubuntu terminal, simply type

```
vscode .
```

in the directory or repository you want to work...

- you can add atom code editor in vscode plugins
- avoid using docker within a vscode session in wsl2 - it has its issues and
- run docker from command line in ubuntu for best results...
- be sure to open the correct ports and add the appropriate web3 provider network to your metamask wallet
- to run a mainnet fork of ethereum for testing - use ganache and in fact you could use this docker actually

> dafidao/mainnet-fork

We used this during development of da-fi.io

Best of luck